# Can Visual Studio 2012 Express for Windows build a Windows store app?

Tags: visual-studio

I'm puzzled about what version of Visual Studio 2012 Express I should go with: Windows 8 or Windows Desktop. The Windows Desktop version is double the size of the Windows 8 version, so does the Windows Desktop Version have all capabilities of the Windows 8 version, such as building a Windows store application?

Answer (score 2):

[According to this explanation page by Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads#d-2010-express):

- Visual Studio 2012 Express **for Windows 8** --> for **Windows store apps**
- Visual Studio 2012 Express for Web --> for regular web apps (ASP.NET)
- Visual Studio 2012 Express for Windows Desktop --> for regular Winforms and WPF apps
- Visual Studio 2012 Express for Windows Phone --> for Windows Phone 8 apps

So: **no** - Visual Studio 2012 Express **for Windows Desktop** is **NOT** suitable to build Windows Store Apps - that would be Visual Studio 2012 **for Windows 8** instead.

Confusing - I agree - but that's marketing at work ......